# Calculator Button on MS Sculpt Keyboard Launches Calculator in the Background

Tags: windows, keyboard, hotkeys

Using the Calculator Button on either the keyboard or numeric key pad launches the calculator app but does not give it focus or bring it to the foreground.

Comment: Any specific OS like windows 7, 8, 8.1 or 10 ?

Comment: Windows 7 and Windows 10, both 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to uninstall Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard Center.